# spring-test dbunit comparison failure of joda datetime fields

Tags: spring, jpa, jodatime, dbunit, spring-test

Wrote a simple junit/spring-test dbunit test to test my jpa entity persistence. A weird thing happens. When dbunit compare my dataset with @ExpectedDatabase file it throws exception comparing joda datetime field:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: value (table=person, row=2, col=birth_date) expected:<1973-11-2[7]> but was:<1973-11-2[6 23:00:00.0]>
    at org.dbunit.assertion.JUnitFailureFactory.createFailure(JUnitFailureFactory.java:39)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DefaultFailureHandler.createFailure(DefaultFailureHandler.java:105)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:208)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.compareData(DbUnitAssert.java:524)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:409)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:253)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:205)
    at org.dbunit.Assertion.assertEquals(Assertion.java:104)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.assertion.DefaultDatabaseAssertion.assertEquals(DefaultDatabaseAssertion.java:33)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.verifyExpected(DbUnitRunner.java:115)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:67)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:158)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:395)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I persist "1973-11-27" but dbunit sees that as a "1973-11-26 23:00:00.0". (an hour earlier). Why? Looks like something with a timezone.

Here is my test class:

```
    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase (value = "classpath:person-expected-data.xml")
    public void testSavePersonEM() {
        logger.info("--- testSavePersonEM ---");
        Person person = new Person("Joe", "King");
        person.setAddress("XXXX XXXXX 27");
        person.setEmail("joe@hotmail.com");
        person.setTelephone("123456789");

        person.setBirthDate(new DateTime("1973-11-27"));

        em.persist(person);
        assertEquals(new Long(2), person.getId());
        assertEquals("1973-11-27", person.getBirthDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        logger.info("new id:" + person.getId());
        logger.info("birthdate: " + person.getBirthDate().toString());
    }
```

logger.info shows "1973-11-27".

Here is the person-expected-data.xml:

```
<dataset>
    <Person id="2" first_name="joe" last_name="king"
        birth_date="1973-11-27" address="bla bla 27" city="bla"
        country="Serbia" email="joe@hotmail.com" telephone="123456798" />
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution by changing  the entity's field data type from org.joda.time.DateTime to org.joda.time.LocalDate. At this moment I don't care about the time or time zone. I just need bare date:

```
...
@Column(name = "birth_date")
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private **LocalDate** birthDate;
...
```

Now tests run without problem.